# MYSQL query disallowing a timestamp column having two values from the same date

Tags: mysql, sql, timestamp

For example if a user inserts '2017-03-13 12:16:18.0' into the timestamp column,
the same user should not be allowed to enter another value in this column IF IT'S ON THE SAME DAY i.e 2017-03-13 (in this case). Or ultimately, update the timestamp column with the previously inserted value ('2017-03-13 12:16:18.0') each time the user tries to insert a timestamp date twice ON THE SAME DAY. I hope I've been explicit enough.

Below is a non-functioning query I came up with, but it shows what I would like the query to do ultimately. Thanks for your help and feedbacks.

```
INSERT INTO hr.entry(id,entry_time)
VALUES (45,
    CASE WHEN '13-03-2017'= CAST(SYSDATE() AS date) THEN
     (UPDATE hr.entry
     SET entry_time =
    (SELECT entry_time
      FROM hr.entry
      WHERE id=45
      AND CAST(entry_time AS date)= CAST(SYSDATE() AS date) ) 
     ELSE 
  SYSDATE());
```

Comment: id= FOREIGN KEY int, entry_time = TIMESTAMP UNIQUE, entry_id = PRIMARY KEY AUTO INCREMENTING

Comment: Why do you have the question tagged MySQL if you are using SQL Server syntax?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could add a `DATE` column to your table, and add a unique index to that column.  Then, when you insert the timestamp into the timestamp column, you could also insert the date from that timestamp into the `DATE` column.  Attempts to insert a timestamp whose date component already exists in that table would cause MySQL to throw an error.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are going to need a trigger, unless you store the timestamp as a *string* using YYYY-MM-DD HH:MI:SS format.  I don't really recommend that.

So, create a trigger that updates a column called `timestamp_date`.  This simply extracts the date part of the timestamp.

With this column, you can define a unique index:

```
create unique index entry_userid_timestampdate on entry(userid, timestamp_date);
```

This will then enforce your condition.

If you decide that you want to store the timestamp as a string, you don't need the trigger (although will need to manually set the "timestamp").  Instead, you can use a prefix:

```
create unique index entry_userid_timestampstr on entry(userid, left(timestamp_date, 10));
```